# Add Ad Banner into listview

Tags: android, listview, admob

Currently I am trying to integrate a Banner from AdMob into my listview. E.g. it should always be shown after 5 listitems and so on. The "regular" list data I am fetching with AsyncTask. Do I need to implement this in my adapter class with a loop?

Adapter Class:

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application> {
    private List<Application> items;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
        }

        Application app = items.get(position);

        if (app != null) {
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
            TextView path = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.path_icon);

            if (icon != null) {

                String sIcon = app.getIcon();

                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(sIcon)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_selfie)
                        .resize(width, height).centerCrop().into(icon);
            }

            if (path != null) {
                path.setText(app.getIcon());
            }

        }

        return v;
    }}
```

Note: I could show a banner successfull on the bottom of the screen, but now I want it every fifth position on the list view. How can I achieve this? Are there some samples? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this my creating two layouts of items in your listview.

One for each five items you show which may include whatever elements use.
Second layout will only contain AdView element.

in getView you need to handle such that after five you use other layout of adview.

You can check [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html) example to kick start.